# How disable JFrame Background but show swing contents

Tags: java, swing, background, jframe

Im looking for some method that disable JFrame or anyother swing containers background to no opaque or disable it but im not talking about trasparent background, but showing controls like button, images...

Something like 'Photoshop startup screen' where there only show a image but background is null disable and mouse would reacts THROUGH of the things that were under empty JFrame background places

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's not possible, any portion of the screen which isn't completely transparent will trap a mouse event

Comment: That’s system dependent, but on Windows, the transparent background *is* click-through. To make Swing components work on a transparent background, you have to either enforce them to be opaque or wrap them into an opaque panel.